# Magento 2: image redirects after migration M1 -> M2

Tags: magento2, product-images, url-rewrite, seo

After successfully migrating M1 to M2 there is the question what to do about the old store's images. We have a lot of images in the google index and they are ranking quite nicely.

For instance a product image:

```
https://www.example.com/media/catalog/product/cache/6/image/265x/5df78bab33555d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/5/h/my_nice_product.jpg
```

I can find it in the google index but it has no equivalence in the new store. Calling this image directly generates a 404 Not Found error.

But when I click that image inside the google search I will automatically be redirected to the product's new URL but not directly to the new image though. The product's redirect has been done by us so no surprise there.

What would be the best solution to redirect these images? Or do I not have to worry about those images as google would find them by itself?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Those all image links are already died. 
In Magento 1, you save the product photos in **file/media/catalog**, however in Magento 2, you need to save them in **file/pub/media/catalog**. Therefore, you got the 404 error, it must has **/pub/** on the URL.

To resolve it, you have 2 options:

1. Create manually a migration script and custom it.
2. Find experienced migration experts to help you custom your data so that your old link won't get 404 error but will be redirected to the new link on your target cart.